# How to store cheesecake for long-term?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, cheesecake

My wife and I decided to have cheesecakes for our wedding last weekend.  We'd like to store some for at least our one-year anniversary.   What is the proper way to store it, and how long can we expect it to last and still be worth eating?   Once she gets completely moved in, we'll have a deep freeze, but we currently just have a couple of refrigerator freezers, though one is rarely opened.

Comment: Congratulations! :-)

Comment: My guess is that you want to wrap it up very very tightly (plastic wrap maybe?) so that it won't dry out, make sure it's airtight, and just toss it in the freezer. The issues with long-term freezer storage are generally things drying out, texture changing, and taking on odors so that the food becomes unpalatable. But I'm no cheesecake expert!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cheesecake kept for 1 year just fine with no discernible off flavors or other problems.

I'm a homebrewer and we wound up putting the cheesecake into the freezer section of our spare 'beer fridge'.   That freezer is pretty much only used for overflow freezer space, and the refrigerator section is used for beer bottles and kegs, and we have had a few apples in the crispers for most of the year, but that's it.   The freezer section was rarely opened more than once per week.

The cheesecake had no off flavors, and only had light water crystallisation on the surface, which was not at all detrimental to our enjoyment of the cake.

This was a plain 'real' cooked cheesecake with graham cracker crust.

So, for a 'good enough' storage method, wrap loosely in foil and store in a freezer that is rarely used, and the cheesecake should be excellent for at least one year.

Comment: I would think that a cheesecake (or anything) surviving that long only wrapped loosely in foil would be an anomaly. Without being wrapped tightly, I'd expect at least freezer burn.

Comment: I won't argue that it will work that way for everyone everywhere, just relaying what worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

[Still tasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16748) gives you 2-3 months on cheesecake in the freezer.  It will be safe indefinitely at freezing temp, but the texture will change somewhat.  As @ElendilTheTall says, foil and plastic wrap are your best bets.  Additionally, I might try freezing it for a day to get solid, and then sticking it in a vacuum sealed bag.  If your seals aren't airtight on something else, then cheesecake will pick up any funky odors in your freezers.

Congrats btw, and I'm gonna let you in on a secret about the eating the wedding cake at 1 year - it *all* tastes worse and some tastes **really bad**.  Normal or cheesecake or whatever, the cake is pretty much always bad by then, but luckily it's not about the cake taste.  It's about reliving the memories and laughing over bad cake.  So don't worry too much about if the cake is not that tasty then - take a bite,remember the wedding, and have a good chuckle.

Comment: FMI also gives 2-3 months for frozen cheesecakes http://www.fmi.org/docs/consumer/foodguides.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can freeze it, wrapped tightly in plastic wrap and foil, but I doubt it will last a year - a couple of months at most. Try it anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I made a lemon/lime cheesecake Dec.2013 and we ate it July 2014. I put the cake on a china plate in a cake box, sealed the box with tape and a big elastic band. When I decided to serve this cake, I removed from the freezer 2 days before and let it sit on the counter for 3 hours. I then put it in my fridge for a day and a half. Lastly I put 1/2 can of cheery pie filling on top.
I had the best reviews for the most flavourable cheesecake. I can only say the cake mellowed. It did not shrink, did not have a bad taste and nobody guessed it was 7 mths in my freezer. So, I say, as long as you seal the cake properly, and it is in your deep freezer, you will not have a problem. Worked for me. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the info given in the below link for their cheesecakes;

> "**Q:**  Can I re-freeze your Cheesecakes?
>   **A:**  Yes.  But, we recommend
>   wrapping them in plastic wrap and putting them back into their boxes
>   and wrapping the boxes with plastic wrap to keep odors from permeating
>   the Cheesecake.  **Do not freeze Cheesecakes with fruit toppings**
>   (fresh or pie type fillings) as the fruit gets yucky.  If you want to
>   freeze the Cheesecake, remove the fruit topping.  **Cheesecakes can be
>   frozen for up to three months.**
>
> **Q:**  Can I save the top to my Wedding Cheesecake for my one year
>   anniversary?
>    **A:**  NO!  Please DO NOT do this..."
>   http://www.sinfulcheesecake.com/FAQs.html

Comment: The link says don't freeze it for your 1 year because you can buy one from them new... Not really relevant here.